# JavaFX WebEngine Button Click

Tags: button, javafx, webengine

PROBLEM: Click a button on a loaded page (via JavaFX WebEngine). Button is

```
<button class="flat_button popup_login_btn button_big" id="install_allow" type="submit" onclick="return login(this)">Button</button>
```

In Java:

```
  HTMLInputElement confirmButton =
    (HTMLInputElement) document.getElementsByTagName("button").item(0);

  confirmButton.click();
```

Console error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.webpane.webkit.dom.HTMLButtonElementImpl cannot be cast to
>   org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLInputElement

RESEARCH: I could try it Javascript way, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20458003/1112963

QUETION: **How to click a webpage button a native JavaFX WebEngine way?**

Comment: There appears to be no accessible API for that. I would use javascript here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as outlined in the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html in the section "Calling back to Java from JavaScript".

Make this class in your webEngine class:

```
public class JavaButtonClicker {
    public void doSomething() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                      "Click Sound");
    }}
```

Put this line in your html:

```
<button  onclick="clicker.doSomething()">Click here to make sound</button>
```

Make a method to do the click in java:

```
private void doClickInJava() {
JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine. executeScript("window");              
                window.setMember("clicker",
                                 new JavaButtonClicker());
                webEngine.executeScript("clicker.doSomething()");
            }
```

Now when the user clicks the button on the page or when you invoke doClickInJava from your webEngine code, it calls doSomething method in JavaButtonClicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HTMLInputElementImpl confirmButton =
    (HTMLInputElementImpl) document.getElementsByTagName("button").item(0);
    confirmButton.click();
```

use HTMLInputElementImpl instead of HTMLinputElement